# Sending payments for eBay purchases via PayPal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal, ebay-api

I'm currently trying to send payments (or start the process to do so in order to load a checkout/confirm webpage) for an eBay item through the PayPal REST API.

eBay's REST API currently allows for purchases to be made via their `PlaceOffer` [endpoint](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/PlaceOffer.html), which returns uniquely identifying information such as a `TransactionID` and `OrderLineItemID`.

From the selling standpoint, the `OrderLineItemID` is used for finding past transactions on the eBay site, so this is definitely used on the back-end to match transactions with purchases/sales.

What I'm not clear on is how to actually send payment for an eBay purchase using PayPal once I have the `OrderLineItemID`. Based on what I've read in their docs, you can accept payments - which I *think* is the correct approach, but I haven't been able to find where to specify this.

**In the end, the PayPal transaction needs to be linked to the eBay `OrderLineItemID`, but I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone shed some light?**

Example request to start a PayPal payment:

```
{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://<return URL here>",
    "cancel_url":"http://<cancel URL here>"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
```

A more thorough request is listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/explore-payment-capabilities/).

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, I didn't think it was possible to pay for an item using the eBay API. Maybe the place offer API only commits to payment? How would listings that require instant payment work?